# Changing home button link dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic, navigation, pushstate

I have a simple problem that hopefully has a simple solution.

Single 'public' home page filled with portfolio items.

I have a duplicated home page that references the exact portfolio content PLUS some addition items only viewable for a private audience.

Clicking on any portfolio item takes you to a detail page.

I want to avoid having 2 versions of the website.

Now, selecting ANY of the portfolio items takes you through to the detail page however the 'home' link points to the public home page. How do I enable it so that the home button is dynamic based on what page a person enters the website.

If they enter through the public home page, I want them to go back there if home is pressed from the detail page.

If a user begins on the private home page, I want the home button to go to the private home page.

It all depends on where a user starts. Help!

Comment: Put something in `sessionStorage` that indicates where they started, and use that in the JS you run when they click on the home link.

Answer (score 0):

So you can look at document.referrer to see what URL referred you to where you currently are.  For instance, if I go from home.html to about.html when I am on about.html document.referrer will tell me that I came from home.

It seems that with that knowledge you can dynamically populate your Home URL.  Without seeing your markup or the structure of your site, this is about as much help as I can offer.